# Query: Updating Multiple Fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

Is it possible to update multiple fields using a query? I was hoping to be able to do this as just an `UPDATE`. Since it's Marketing Cloud, I have to start things with `SELECT` and I'm just not sure how to go about it.

```
SELECT 
EmailAddress, AgentName, AgentNumber, 
  CASE
    WHEN AgentNumber = '123' THEN '1@email.com'
    WHEN AgentNumber = '456' THEN '2@email.com'
    WHEN AgentNumber = '789' THEN '3@email.com'
  END as SendingEmail 
FROM TestDataExt
```

Would anyone know how can I get the above code to update two fields (*SendingEmail and AgentName*) when the `AgentNumber` is equal to something?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do...it's updating `AgentName` and `SendingEmail` your code should already do this. Have you tried to do this? what error did it give you?

Comment: The example is only updating SendingEmail. I want to add something that will update BOTH SendingEmail AND AgentName at the same time. It would be similar to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp BUT the Marketing Cloud queries require me to start  with SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, I assume you want to update the field `AgentName` with a value..let call this `YourNewValue`

Try this

```
SELECT 
'YourNewValue' as AgentName
  ,CASE
    WHEN AgentNumber = '123' THEN '1@email.com'
    WHEN AgentNumber = '456' THEN '2@email.com'
    WHEN AgentNumber = '789' THEN '3@email.com'
  END as SendingEmail 
FROM TestDataExt
```

This query will Update the table with `YourNewValue` for all the entire column..not sure how much sense this makes.

Something like this would make more sense:

```

```
SELECT 
EmailAddress, AgentNumber, 

  CASE
    WHEN AgentNumber = '123' THEN 'Bob'
    WHEN AgentNumber = '456' THEN 'Alice'
    WHEN AgentNumber = '789' THEN 'John'
  END as AgentName 

  ,CASE
    WHEN AgentNumber = '123' THEN '1@email.com'
    WHEN AgentNumber = '456' THEN '2@email.com'
    WHEN AgentNumber = '789' THEN '3@email.com'
  END as SendingEmail 
FROM TestDataExt
```